# C++ windows program consumes 30% CPU, outdated API usage?

Tags: c, windows

I have been following the Cprogramming tutorial on windows/OpenGl programming, and have had good success so far; asides from the fact that my very simple windows program consumes 30% of the CPU, displays the spinning, unresponsive cursor, and does not exit asides from usage of task manager.

as this tutorial targeted a much older version of windows than the one I am using( 8 ), It is very possible that I am abusing the API. I would think it most likely that I have either

- A): neglected an important file to include,
- B): made use of a
  still-functional but buggy piece of windows software, or
- C):
  misprogrammed a portion of the API( WndProc, !done loop, maybe? ) to
  cause it to behave errantly.

My program code is identical to the one at this site, with the subtraction of "stdafx.h"( I could not find this header, which might be my problem ), and the addition of a few files I wrote myself, which describe the independent program I'm working on, and worked fine by themselves.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_first_windows_app.html

Ideally, someone will be able to show me either my error, or the 'right' way of programming for windows 8.

Edit: Here's the code( Thanks robin.koch for while(Getmessage()) :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;

        HDC hDC;

        char string[] = "Hello, world!";

        switch (message){

        case WM_CREATE:
                    return 0;
                    break;

                case WM_CLOSE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;
                    break;


                case WM_PAINT:
                    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);

                    SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));//blue text

                    TextOut(hDC, 150, 150, string, sizeof(string) - 1);
                    EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);

                    return 0;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;


        }//switch(message)




    };


    int APIENTRY WinMain(   HINSTANCE       hInstance,
                            HINSTANCE       hPrevInstance,
                            LPSTR           lpCmdLine,
                            int             nCmdShow
                ){  

            WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
            HWND hwnd;//window handle
            MSG msg;
            bool done;



        windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        windowClass.lpszClassName = "MyClass";
        windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass)){
            return 0;
        }


        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,//extended style
            "MyClass",//App name
            "A real win app",//app name
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | //window style
            WS_VISIBLE |
            WS_SYSMENU,
            100, 100,       //x/y coords
            400, 400,       //width, height)
            NULL, //parent handle
            NULL, //Menu handle
            hInstance, //Application instance
            NULL//No extra parameters
            );


        //check if failed window creation

        if (!hwnd)
            return 0;

        done = false;


        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

            return msg.wParam;}
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a problem with your message loop. Can you post some code?

Comment: stdafx.h is the Visual C++ "precompiled header".  It won't cause a problem to remove it, it's just a compiler option to speed up compilation.

Comment: Well, OK, when you debugged it, where was it looping?

Comment: I'm confused. The question doesn't have a PeekMessage loop, but the answers say that the problem is the PeekMessage loop.

Comment: he posted his code after the answer. he already updated it. the original code can be seen following the link he posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(!done)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //check for a quit message
        {
            done = true; //if found, quit app
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Translate and dispatch to event queue*/
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

This is why you have such a high CPU Load. [PeekMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't block if there is no message available, it just returns false. So, because of the while loop, you are calling this function again and again and again... use the [GetMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead.

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    if(!IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
```

This is a example how I use GetMessage() in my current Project.
Also the `default:` path in your window proc should not just `break`, but call

```
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

This makes sure that messages that you do not handle yourself are processed by the default function. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for details.
This is how would write the window proc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
        HDC hDC;
        char string[] = "Hello, world!";

        switch (message){

        case WM_CREATE:
                    break;
                // WM_CLOSE is used if we want to do something BEFORE the window is destroyed. WM_CLOSE is now handled by the DefWindowProc. We handle WM_DESTROY instead
                case WM_DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0); // here we are telling the message loop in WinMain to stop
                    return 0; // here we don't want the DefWindowProc to be called. So we return before it is called.
                    break;
                case WM_PAINT:
                    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);

                    SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));//blue text

                    TextOut(hDC, 150, 150, string, sizeof(string) - 1);
                    EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);

                    break;
        }//switch(message)
        // Always call the DefWindowProc
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Oh, FFS, PeekMessage loops:(

Comment: Still, a wasteful, CPU-eating, crazy PeekMessage() loop should not, in itself, result in an 'unresponsive' cursor :(

Comment: Thanks! works great; program now uses about zero resources. The program is still unresponsive to input, I will post the code.

Comment: see my updated answer, hope that fixes it.